# Fetch Twitter Timeline as XML/JSON, show in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, xml, twitter, windows-8

I'm currently following a tutorial on how  to show Twitter feeds with LINQ to XML in C#. However, seeing as Microsoft has replaced **WebClient** with **HTTPClient**, I'm unsure how to proceed on my quest of integrating this into my Windows 8 application.
The tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117614/How-to-query-twitter-public-status-using-LINQ-to-X

The thing is that I'm "halfway" used to **DownloadStringCompleted**, which I believe is not in the **HTTPClient** api. So after searching for a while on the async/await functionality, I mixed some of my knowledge together with some tutorials and snippets I found, but what I ended up with would not work:

```
    public async Task<XElement> GetXmlAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=VladimirPutin");
        var text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return XElement.Parse(text.Result);

        XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(text.Result);
        listboxTweetsSecond.ItemsSource = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                                          select new UserTweet
                                          {
                                              UserImageSrc = tweet.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
                                              UserMessage = tweet.Element("text").Value,
                                              UserName = tweet.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value
                                          };

    }
```

*(Yeah, the Twitter username is just a placeholder)*
I do not need an entire code as an answer, but I'd love it if someone could point out where I should go from here, as well as what I should do in general, as this (of course) does not work (as in, it does not show anything when I run it/debug mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the line

```
return XElement.Parse(text.Result);
```

and it should probably work.

Having done that (i.e. you are no longer returning an XElement) you can probably change the method signature top return just a task.

```
public async Task GetXmlAsync()
{
    // method body
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure the method would like to return something? It outputs the following error: "MainPage.GetXmlAsync()': not all code paths return a value".

Comment: It doesn't need to return anything as you've written it, but if you really want to pull back the XElement, put the "return" line right at the end after you have set your ItemsSource

Comment: Removing the XElement solved everything, just didn't see your edit right away. Thanks a bunch, that actually solved everything :)

Comment: Would you know of any way to limit the amount of tweets being fetched? Let's say 10?